# How do I add a folder shared with everyone in Onedrive to my account?

Tags: onedrive

I use OneDrive for Business (through my university).

My adviser shared a folder with me. I subsequently received an e-mail which said in the subject line "[my advisor's name] shared the folder "[folder name]" with you". In the body of the e-mail, it provides a link to the folder which is marked as "This link will work for anyone".

When I click the link, there is absolutely no option for me to add the folder to my account. When I go to "shared" in my account, that folder doesn't exist. How can I add the folder that my adviser shared with me to my personal OneDrive account?

Answer (score 0):

You can add it following these steps (as mentioned at the [office site](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/add-and-sync-shared-folders-to-onedrive-8a63cd47-1526-4cd8-bd09-ee3f9bfc1504)):

1. In the OneDrive navigation pane, under OneDrive, click Shared. Folders you can add to your OneDrive are marked Can edit.

[image]

2. Find the folder you want to add, and click the circle in the folder's tile to select it.
3. Click Add to my OneDrive. Or, if you prefer, you can right-click the folder and then click Add to my OneDrive.

[image]

**Important: The Add to my OneDrive option isn't available when**:

- You're signed in with a work or school account.
- You've already added the folder to your OneDrive, or you have more than one folder selected. (You can't add multiple folders at the same time.)
- The item you're trying to add isn't a folder. (Add to my OneDrive isn't available for individual files or for collections of files such as albums.)

**Could any of the last reasons be your case?**